# cached image Date in AFImageRequestOperation

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

I'm using `AFImageRequestOperation` to download hundreds of jpg from my server.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:20];
AFImageRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {}
                                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {}
                                                ];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:picture] append:NO];
[downloadQueue addOperation:operation];
```

If I delete them all (removing all images in Documents Folder) and start download again, the first X (depends on how far I got during last download process) operations are processed immediately. It seems like the images downloaded from the previous process are stored (cached) somewhere. I also checked the Documents Folder for the simulator and the images are downloaded correctly. So how can I make sure the download process really starts from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating the `NSURLRequest`, use this instead:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData;
```

This policy is described in the docs the following way: *Specifies that the existing cache data may be used provided the origin source confirms its validity, otherwise the URL is loaded from the origin source.*

You can check the cache policies of NSURLRequest [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: although your suggestion seems to be the right thing to do, NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData policy is not yet implemented as of iOS 7.1. Refer to this article http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/